# Leaflet.label and MarkerCluster problem with zoom dependent add/remove layers

Tags: leaflet, labeling

Here's the setup:   I have a leaflet map with point data,  to which I have applied [leaflet.label](https://github.com/leaflet/Leaflet.label) and [leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). I add the clustered point data at a particular zoom level (code below). All works as planned until I zoom back out (points removed) and in again (points added). **The labels no longer work *for the points that don't get clustered.*** Labels still work for points within a cluster (even if they become unclustered with zoom.)

[image: gif showing label problem]

Is there something in my code that's throwing it off when it re adds the point cluster layer? Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?  Or can anyone suggest something, such as binding the label somewhere else, etc?

```
    var cpWells = new L.geoJson(json_cpWellsMin, {
        onEachFeature: pop_cpWellsMin,
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, doStylecpWellsMin(feature))
                .bindLabel(feature.properties['wellID'], {
                    direction: 'auto',
                    offset: [20, -12.5]
            })
        }
    });

    var clusterWells = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        maxClusterRadius: 20,
        spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 4
    });
    clusterWells.addLayer(cpWells);

    map.on('zoomend ', function(e) {
        if (map.getZoom() < 10) {
            map.removeLayer(clusterWells)
            map.addLayer(json_countyPoints)
            json_countiesJSON.setStyle({
                'fillOpacity': '0.7'
            });
        } else if (map.getZoom() >= 10) {
            map.addLayer(clusterWells)
            map.removeLayer(json_countyPoints)
            json_countiesJSON.setStyle({
                'fillOpacity': '0.0'
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I believe it has to do because you never bindPopup to the marker. 
You should try to iterate through your data and add the features you want the marker to display into a marker variable. Then you add that newly made marker layer var into your markercluster variable and now the points that do not get clustered should also have a popup when they are selected.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response. I am actually having the issue with the leaflet.label plugin, rather than the leaflet popup.